# What is the best/most elegant way to write a struct contiguously to a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, struct, padding

I'm trying to write image data to a BMP file. I found this [website](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece264/17au/hw/HW15) which proposes the following struct for the file header:

```
typedef struct {             // Total: 54 bytes
  uint16_t  type;             // Magic identifier: 0x4d42
  uint32_t  size;             // File size in bytes
  uint16_t  reserved1;        // Not used
  uint16_t  reserved2;        // Not used
  uint32_t  offset;           // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
  uint32_t  dib_header_size;  // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
  int32_t   width_px;         // Width of the image
  int32_t   height_px;        // Height of image
  uint16_t  num_planes;       // Number of color planes
  uint16_t  bits_per_pixel;   // Bits per pixel
  uint32_t  compression;      // Compression type
  uint32_t  image_size_bytes; // Image size in bytes
  int32_t   x_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
  int32_t   y_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
  uint32_t  num_colors;       // Number of colors  
  uint32_t  important_colors; // Important colors 
} BMPHeader;
```

I know that C/C++ does not guarantee that the data from a struct will be stored contiguously, So simply writing the header struct to the file like so:

```
BMPHeader header(width, height, bytespp, fileSize);
int num_read = fwrite(&header, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, 1, fp);
```

or so:

```
BMPHeader* header = new BMPHeader(width, height, bytespp, fileSize);
int num_read = fwrite(header, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, 1, fp);
```

using the following constructor (this is probably unnecessary information, but including it incase it might be useful):

```
BMPHeader(
        unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned short bytespp, unsigned int fileSize) : 
        type(MAGIC_VALUE), size(fileSize),
        reserved1(RESERVED), reserved2(RESERVED), offset(BMP_HEADER_SIZE), 
        dib_header_size(40), width_px(width), height_px(height), num_planes(NUM_PLANE),
        bits_per_pixel(bytespp*BITS_PER_BYTE), compression(COMPRESSION),
        image_size_bytes(width * height * bytespp), x_resolution_ppm(0x00),
        y_resolution_ppm(0x00), num_colors(0x00), important_colors(IMPORTANT_COLORS)
    {
    }
```

won't work since there is no guarantee that the variables will be stored in the order that they are written, nor is there a guarantee that there won't be padding between the variables.

Regardless, I tried it anyways and, unsurprisingly, it didn't work.

My question is this: Is there any way to write the data to a file in a more elegant way than having to individually write each member variable to the file in the order that I want?

I tried instantiating the struct both onto the heap as a `BMPHeader*`, as well as on the stack.

I also tried using a union like so:

```
struct BMPHeader
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned short type;                            // Magic identifier: 0x4d42
            unsigned int size;                          // File size in bytes
            unsigned short reserved1;               // Not used
            unsigned short reserved2;               // Not used
            unsigned int offset;                        // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
            unsigned int dib_header_size;   // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
            unsigned int width_px;                  // Width of the image
            unsigned int height_px;             // Height of image
            unsigned short num_planes;              // Number of color planes
            unsigned short bits_per_pixel;      // Bits per pixel
            unsigned int compression;           // Compression type
            unsigned int image_size_bytes; // Image size in bytes
            unsigned int x_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
            unsigned int y_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
            unsigned int num_colors;                // Number of colors
            unsigned int important_colors; // Important colors
        };
        unsigned char raw[54];
    };
```

to see if I could write the array to the file, but I ran into the same issue.

Comment: In C++ at least, the order of the members is not changed by any existing compiler, and will be regulated in C++23. You can also verify the total size with `sizeof` to rule out any padding. Then you only have big endian vs little endian to worry about. :-)

Comment: Most people would just throw in `#pragma pack` or an equivalent compiler-specific incantation and call it a day.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one tag and delete the other. If you need answers in both languages, post separate questions. Conflating tags consumes the attention of people who want to follow one tag but not the other and can frustrate people in the future seeking an answer to a question for C but finding C++ answers or vice-versa.

Comment: How about using a std::vector<unsigned char> to represent the BMP format, and simply write the vector to file..

I found this github library (https://github.com/marc-q/libbmp/tree/master) might be useful...

Comment: The site you cite mentions a `#pragma`, but it doesn't show it...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've removed the C tag. I am compiling this as C++ code, I'm put C here since I'm using the FILE type, which I believe is more of a C thing.

Comment: the keyword is [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit you're right. That fixed it. Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks all. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Yksisarvinen** and **n. m. will see y'all on Reddit** mentioned in the comments above, I didn't include the `pragma pack` directive.

Here is the change that fixed it:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct BMPHeader
{
    uint16_t type;                          // Magic identifier: 0x4d42
    uint32_t size;                          // File size in bytes
    uint16_t reserved1;             // Not used
    uint16_t reserved2;             // Not used
    uint32_t offset;                        // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
    uint32_t dib_header_size;   // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
    uint32_t width_px;                  // Width of the image
    uint32_t height_px;             // Height of image
    uint16_t num_planes;                // Number of color planes
    uint16_t bits_per_pixel;        // Bits per pixel
    uint32_t compression;           // Compression type
    uint32_t image_size_bytes; // Image size in bytes
    uint32_t x_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
    uint32_t y_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
    uint32_t num_colors;                // Number of colors
    uint32_t important_colors; // Important colors

    BMPHeader(
        unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned short bytespp, unsigned int fileSize) : 
        type(MAGIC_VALUE), size(fileSize),
        reserved1(RESERVED), reserved2(RESERVED), offset(BMP_HEADER_SIZE), 
        dib_header_size(40), width_px(width), height_px(height), num_planes(NUM_PLANE),
        bits_per_pixel(bytespp*BITS_PER_BYTE), compression(COMPRESSION),
        image_size_bytes(width * height * bytespp), x_resolution_ppm(0x00),
        y_resolution_ppm(0x00), num_colors(0x00), important_colors(IMPORTANT_COLORS)
    {
    }
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft kept using this structure for years and a single write to a file works with the standard settings of struct types in Visual Studio.

But there is a nasty trap:

```
#pragma pack(push,2)
    typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER
    {
        WORD bfType;
        DWORD bfSize;
        WORD bfReserved1;
        WORD bfReserved2;
        DWORD bfOffBits;
    } BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

must be enforced to guarantee that the fields `bfType` and `bfReserved1/2` are stored on two bytes.

By contrast, the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` (and later variants) does not use this setting.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the most elegant method is to copy the methods into a buffer.  This allows you to controls the spacing (if any) and also Endianness:

```
struct BMPHeader
{ // Total: 54 bytes
  uint16_t  type;             // Magic identifier: 0x4d42
  uint32_t  size;             // File size in bytes
  uint16_t  reserved1;        // Not used
  uint16_t  reserved2;        // Not used
  uint32_t  offset;           // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
  uint32_t  dib_header_size;  // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
  //...
  void write_to_buffer(uint8_t *& p_buffer) const;
};

void BMPHeader::write_to_buffer(uint8_t *& p_buffer) const
{
    *p_buffer = (uint8_t *) &type;
    p_buffer += sizeof(type);

    *p_buffer = (uint8_t *) &size;
    p_buffer += sizeof(size);
    //...
}
```

You can then use it with block writing:

```
uint8_t  buffer[54];
BMPHeader header;
//...
char * p_buffer = &buffer[0];
header.write_to_buffer(p_buffer);
destination_file.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Similarly, write a method to read the members from a buffer.  The read works really nice for non-POD members, such as strings.

An accompanying method `size_in_buffer()` would return the accumulative size that each member would occupy in the buffer.  This is great when allocating a dynamic array (buffer) to hold the data.

The efficiency is based on the rational that writing to memory is faster than writing to a file.  Also, block writing to a file is faster and more efficient than many small writes for each member separately.  A stream is most efficient when it is kept running.

Also, search the internet for "C++ serialization".

*Note:  This version does not require any compiler directives and should work on all platforms that support files.*